# textContent results in invalid string in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

If field 3 of a row in an html table is

> All "Dogs' go to heaven.

the browser console will show the following inner list (after the function filldb() is called). Note the *mismatched interior quotes* in the textContent from that row/field of the table and in the resulting list element.

```
["1", "101", "3/S4.1", "All "dogs' go to heaven.", "4*3*2", "5", "60", "1", "30-00.0", "750.96"]

 function filldb(){
    estRows=[];
    rows=e_tbody.rows;
    // 'rows' is now the collection of rows in your dynamically output table.
    var len=rows.length;
    var lnItm=[];
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        lnItm=[];
        lnItm.push(rows[i].cells[0].textcontent);
        lnItm.push(rows[i].cells[1].textcontent);
        lnItm.push(rows[i].cells[2].textcontent);
        lnItm.push(rows[i].cells[3].textcontent);
        --- <snip> ---
        lnItm.push(rows[i].cells[9].textcontent);
        estRows.push(lnItm);
    }
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log(estRows[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm confused how an element of a JavaScript array can be an invalid string. Explain? Something about textContent not being parsed?

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive -> `textcontent !== textContent`

Comment: `"All "Dogs' go to heaven."` The quote was expected to be closed after heaven. But it was closed before Dogs.

Comment: `"All "Dogs' go to heaven."` should be somthing like `"All \"Dogs' go to heaven."`

Answer (score 0):

parsed of course, see the console ["a", "All "Dogs' go to heaven."] the `"` inside string is red and others are black,this is the rule when log array, you can use `JSON.stringify` to log all as string

```js
var arr = ['a']
arr.push(`All "Dogs' go to heaven.`)
console.log(arr)
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```